# Complexity of defining prime numbers

Tags: lo.logic, prime-numbers, computational-complexity

We can define prime numbers by the following formula in the language of arithmetic:
$$P(x):= x>1 \land \forall y< x(\exists z\leq x(y\cdot z =x)\to y=1) $$

This formula is $\Delta_0$ and its properties can be proved in strong enough systems of arithmetic, but in some sub intuitionistic theories of arithmetic properties of this formula can not be proven. By AKS algorithm prime numbers are $\Delta^b_1$ definable in the language of bounded arithmetics (Actually these numbers are polynomial time decidable). My question is about the complexity of defining prime numbers in the language of arithmetic.

> Q1. Is there any $E_1$ formula for defining prime numbers?
>
> Q2. Is there any $E^+_1$ formula for defining prime numbers?

$E^+_1$ formulas are $E_1$ formulas which do not have implication or negation.

Comment: @BjørnKjos-Hanssen: $\psi$ is an $E_1$ formula iff $\psi := \exists x_1<t_1\exists x_2<t_2...\exists x_n<t_n\phi(x_1,...,x_n)$ such that $\phi(x_1,...,x_n)$ be quantifier free.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused: isn't implication just a hidden universal quantifier?

Comment: @fedja: Yes, They are alike. What part of my question make you confused?

Comment: Q1 was answered already at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/106409/is-there-an-e-1-definition-of-primality

Comment: Since inequality is definable by an $E_1^+$ formula, Q1 and Q2 are equivalent.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek: In strong enough theory of arithmetics, Q1 and Q2 are equivalent, but in some sub intuitionistic theories $\neg x=y$ is not equivalent to an $E^+_1$ formula and therefore the behavior of $E_1$ formulas are different from $E^+_1$ formulas. For example $I\exists^+_1\not\vdash MRDP$, but $I\exists_1\vdash MRDP$. So working with an $\exists^+_1$ formula in $I\exists^+_1$ is better than working with an $\exists_1$ formula.